# How to rename and or remove a pub package

Tags: dart, dart-pub

How can I rename or delete packages?

Currently I have a package x that I want to split into separate components. Want to keep the main Name but extend it for these components eg "x a" "x b"

Current workaround would be: I keep the old one ,linking to the 2 new once in the read me page

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to file an issue ticket for removing/renaming your package as that's not possible to do yourself at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. Issued [12094](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12094)

Comment: @Kai so do you know if I could contact someone that will change the name for me then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the following [response of Nathan Weizenbaum](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8070#c1) on a similar request :

> We don't like deleting packages that people might be depending on. The best thing to do is probably upload a new version with a README that points users to the "redisclient" package (or "redis_client", which conforms better to the package naming conventions).